# Number of positive and negative eigenvalues

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, linear-algebra

The Jacobian of the inversion of the Lobachevsky space is given by $$J_{\mu\nu} = \delta_{\mu\nu} - 2 \frac{z_\mu z_\nu}{z^2}, $$ where $z_\mu$ are real numbers, $z_0 > 0$ and $z^2 = \delta^{\alpha\beta} z_\alpha z_\beta$. (I'm considering $d+1$ dimensions, so $\mu$ goes from $0$ to $d$.)

Seen as a matrix, this is orthogonal, so we certainly know that its eigenvalues are $\pm 1$.

However, can we say something about the number of positive and negative eigenvalues? There should be $d$ eigenvalues $+1$ and $1$ eigenvalue $-1$.

Comment: Hint: The matrix has the form $J=\mathbf{1}_{d+1}-2n n^T$, where $n$ is a unit vector ($n^T n=1$).  The rest is trivial.

Comment: I don't see how this is trivial? I also don't want to go to other notation, I'd like to stay with the indices. But maybe that's exactly where my issue is?

Comment: Obviously $Jn=-n$ and $Jx=x \; \forall x$ orthogonal to $n$. How many linear independent vectors orthogonal to $n$ do you have in this vector space?

Comment: $d$ linear independent vectors. But can we do it in this notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm expanding on the comment by @Hyperon. The matrix you have can be written as
$$
J = I - 2 n \otimes n , \qquad n_\mu = \frac{z_\mu}{\sqrt{z^2}}.
$$
Let $(n_\mu,t_\mu^i)$ be basis vectors on ${\mathbb R}^{d+1}$ satisfying ($i=1,\cdots,d$)
$$
n \cdot n = 1, \qquad t^i \cdot t^j = \delta^{ij} , \qquad n \cdot t^i = 0 .
$$
Then,
$$
J \cdot n = - n , \qquad J \cdot t^i = + t^i
$$
$J$ is a $(d+1) \times (d+1)$ matrix so it has $d+1$ eigenvalues. From the above, we find that it has exactly $1$ negative eigenvalue ($-1$) and $d$ positive eigenvalues ($+1$).